# Search bar and suggestions with matches based on JSON object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Pretty new to React. Was given the task of implementing a search and as the user types their search, display the suggested matches with a price, image, and name based on a JSON object & match. I got some of it but I'm at loss of how to proceed. Any guidance or help would be appreciated. The `onSearch` method is where the search gets triggered. Thanks

Below is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../../../server/data'; 


class Menu extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        showingSearch: false,
        data
    };
}

/**
 * Shows or hides the search container
 * @memberof Menu
 * @param e [Object] - the event from a click handler
 */
showSearchContainer(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        showingSearch: !this.state.showingSearch,
        query:'',
        data:[],
    });
}

/**
 * Calls upon search change
 * @memberof Menu
 * @param e [Object] - the event from a text change handler
 */
onSearch(e) {
    const {value} = e.target;
    this.setState({
      query:value
    });
    data.map((products, index)=>{
       return <span> {products.price} </span> /*started the map method here to display object*/
    })
    // Start Here
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return (

        <header className="menu">
            <div className="menu-container">
                <div className="menu-holder">
                    <h1>Trying to find item</h1>
                    <nav>
                        <a href="#" className="nav-item">Specials</a>
                        <a href="#" className="nav-item">Sales</a>
                        <a href="#" className="nav-item">Stores</a>
                        <a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.showSearchContainer(e)}>
                            <i className="material-icons search">search</i>
                        </a>
                        <div>
                        {data.map((products, index)=>{
                           return <span> {products.price} </span>
                        })}
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={(this.state.showingSearch ? "showing " : "") + "search-container"}>
                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onSearch(e)} />
                <a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.showSearchContainer(e)}>
                    <i className="material-icons close">close</i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
  }
}


/**Imported JSON file*/
var data = [
{
    "_id": "001",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "20.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N0CA_430.png",
    "name": "Damage Reverse Oil Conditioner",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "oil",
        "conditioner"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "002",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "22.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N0EN01_430.png",
    "name": "Volume Advance Conditioner",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "conditioner"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "003",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "30.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N0EY01_430.png",
    "name": "Volume Advance Shampoo",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "shampoo"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "004",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "20.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N0FP_430.png",
    "name": "Damage Reverse Oil Shampoo",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "oil",
        "shampoo"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "005",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "7.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N0H101_430.png",
    "name": "Color Sustain Pro",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "treatment"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "006",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "38.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N0J801_430.png",
    "name": "Damage Reverse Hair Serum",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "serum"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "007",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "38.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N0J901_430.png",
    "name": "Damage Reverse Restorative Hair Treatment",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "treatment"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "008",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "27.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N0PL01_430.png",
    "name": "Super Sleek Conditioner",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "conditioner"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "009",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "17.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N0YJ01_430.png",
    "name": "Rare Blend Oil",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "oil",
        "rare blend"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "010",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "22.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N08X_430.png",
    "name": "Dry Recovery Hydrating Shampoo",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "hydrating",
        "shampoo"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "011",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "22.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N08Y_430.png",
    "name": "Dry Recovery Hydrating Conditioner",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "hydrating",
        "conditioner"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "012",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "12.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N12R01_430.png",
    "name": "Rare Blend Deep Conditioner",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "conditioner",
        "rare blend"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "013",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "25.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N13J01_430.png",
    "name": "Rare Blend Moisture-Rich Cleansing Conditioner",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "cleansing",
        "conditioner",
        "rare blend"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "014",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "17.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N15E01_430.png",
    "name": "Rare Blend Protecting Treatment",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "treatment",
        "rare blend"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "015",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "15.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N17R01_430.png",
    "name": "Rare Blend Oil Rejuvenating Therapy Lightweight Texture",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "oil",
        "rare blend"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "016",
    "isActive": "false",
    "price": "25.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N098_430.png",
    "name": "Damage Reverse Restorative Hair Treatment",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "treatment"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "017",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "17.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N16201_430.png",
    "name": "Rare Blend Infusion Shampoo",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "shampoo",
        "rare blend"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "018",
    "isActive": "true",
    "price": "20.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N16401_430.png",
    "name": "Damage Reverse Thickening Shampoo",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "shampoo"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "019",
    "isActive": "false",
    "price": "23.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N16501_430.png",
    "name": "Damage Reverse Thickening Conditioner",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "conditioner"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "020",
    "isActive": "false",
    "price": "40.00",
    "picture": "/img/products/N19601_430.png",
    "name": "Rare Blend Oil Moisture Therapy Medium Texture",
    "about": "Dolor voluptate velit consequat duis. Aute ad officia fugiat esse anim exercitation voluptate excepteur pariatur sit culpa duis qui esse. Labore amet ad eu veniam nostrud minim labore aliquip est sint voluptate nostrud reprehenderit. Ipsum nostrud culpa consequat reprehenderit.",
    "tags": [
        "ojon",
        "texture"
    ]
 }
 ];
module.exports = data;
```

Comment: You've used `{data.map(....)}` shouldn't you use the `data` array from the state (`{this.state.data.map(....)`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to set a filter to what is typed into `<input>` and then render the elements after filtering them by this value. It'd look smth like this:

```
// Set the filter value
onSearch(e) {
  const {  value } = e.target;
  this.setState({
    query: value
  });
}

// Filter the items by the value in your render method

render() {
    const { data, query } = this.state;
    const filteredData = !query
      ? data
      : data.filter(product =>
          product.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
        );

    return (
      <header className="menu">
        <div className="menu-container">
          <div className="menu-holder">
            <h1>Trying to find item</h1>
            <nav>
              <a href="#" className="nav-item">
                Specials
              </a>
              <a href="#" className="nav-item">
                Sales
              </a>
              <a href="#" className="nav-item">
                Stores
              </a>
              <a href="#" onClick={e => this.showSearchContainer(e)}>
                <i className="material-icons search">search</i>
              </a>
              <div>
                {filteredData.map((product, index) => (
                  <span> {product.price} </span>
                ))}
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          className={
            (this.state.showingSearch ? "showing " : "") + "search-container"
          }
        >
          <input type="text" onChange={e => this.onSearch(e)} />
          <a href="#" onClick={e => this.showSearchContainer(e)}>
            <i className="material-icons close">close</i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks for this, I'm getting `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, isActive, price, picture, name, about, tags}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`. I did some research on that too but I'm not sure yet why it's breaking.

Comment: How does your data look like? I assumed it was an array of objects.

Comment: It's actually imported at the top, but I included it in the code so you could view it. It's an array of objects so I'm not sure why it's failing.

Comment: @erics15 sorry, my bad, I forgot to render the filtered data properly. Updated the answer, now it works. Also here's a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-pn6cj

Comment: @erics15 remember to accept the answer if it solves your issue :)

Comment: Sure thing, accepted ;).  I am still working through a few things but it's more to figure out how to autocomplete this with suggestions based on the JSON

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function, which takes the original array, your query string, and an array of object keys to check for in your search.

```
const searchByKeys = (array, query, keys) => {
  const lowSearch = query.toLowerCase();
  return array.filter((item) => {
      return keys.some((key) =>  String(item[key]).toLowerCase().includes(lowSearch) 
      );
  });
};
```

So onSearch you would generate a new array of objects that you would display.

```
onSearch(e) {
  const {value} = e.target;
  this.setState({
    query: value,
    searchResults: searchByKeys(data, value, ["name"]);
  });
}
```

Then you can use `this.state.searchResults` in your render method with your `.map()` method.

Comment: Saving filtered results to the state isn't a good idea and not really how it's normally done in React. It's easier to filter at render time.